# How to solve first order linear recurrence relation using characteristic equation method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Consider the recurrence relation
$$ a(n) = 3\cdot a(n-1) + 2 ,\quad a(0) = 1.$$

Using the method of iteration, I found the solution to be

$$a(n) = 2\cdot 3^n - 1.$$

I would like to know how to form the characteristic equation for the given recurrence relation and solve it using that.

Comment: Do you know about the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, but everything what I've done so far using characteristic polynomial was only for second order relations, and I am not getting how to use the same in this case

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link but I can see that all examples there are for second order relations. As mentioned previously, I am specifically looking for solving first order relations using the characteristic equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous part is $a_n-3a_{n-1}=0$, yielding characteristic polynomial $x-3$ with a single root $x=3$.  So the homogeneous solution is $a_n=A \cdot 3^n$, and the general solution is $a_n=A \cdot 3^n + B$.  Now $1=a_0=A+B$ and $5=a_1=3A+B$, so $A=2$ and $B=-1$.